# Which edition of Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica of Isaac Newton would you recommend to me?

Tags: mathematics-education, books, physics

I'm searching for a good edition of Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica of Isaac Newton in English. Which edition of the Principia can you suggest me? If it's possible, cheap and similar to original with the original proofs of Isaac Newton.

I'm sorry for my poor English, I'm just learning it.

Comment: I would recommend you skip it entirely.

Comment: It's not what you asked but is related (and interesting): Arnold's [Newton's principia read 300 years later](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284757805_Newton%27s_principia_read_300_years_later)

Comment: @Asaf Can you elaborate why?

Comment: @lcv: There's often this feeling—especially by amateur or beginning mathematicians—of "reading the masters". But mathematics is not philosophy. Nor it is physics. It is different from anything else. It's not new points of view vs. old ones, or ultimately personal opinions. In mathematics, it's the same material, chewed and regurgitated from modern points of view, in modern language. Reading "classics" *should* be done, but only after you have the knowledge from the modern point of view. For historical perspective. Not in order to *learn* from it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : What makes you think that gmorkk is trying to learn mathematics from the Principia? I interpreted gmorkk as saying that he's just learning English. Also the Principia contains a lot of physics, not just mathematics.

Comment: @Timothy: Well, (1) it's a mathematics website, not a physics website; and (2) it's not the first time I see people online saying that they want to study mathematics from "the masters", and while it's true the OP did not say *why* they are searching for a copy, I would find it a bit odd to use that as a tool for learning English (I mean, it would be fine if your native tongue is Latin, I guess), I'm just using my experience to deduce this.

Comment: One big problem with the Principia is that it uses an impoverished set of mathematical tools. He didn't use algebra or calculus because his audience didn't know algebra or calculus. For example, that makes the proof of elliptical orbits extremely lengthy (dozens of pages IIRC), whereas a modern proof using freshman calculus can be a couple of pages.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure, I now understand (and agree with) your comment. In general I think reading classics is great, also for learning, as long as they share a large fraction of nowadays "notation" (intended in general sense). There are also many examples where the "classic" paper is much clearer than the modern wannabe exposition (an example is the adiabatic theorem in quantum mechanics).

Answer (score 23):

The difficulty is not in the language that Newton uses, but in the incredibly original viewpoint that he takes.  Get a good translation, by all means, but you'll also need the help of a good guide.

One of the best such guides I ever found was S. Chandrasekhar's fantastic "Newton's *Principia* for the Common Reader", Oxford University Press, 1995. (Don't be fooled by the title, though, apparently Chandrasekhar had a much higher opinion of the 'common reader' than is warranted by the available evidence.)

It doesn't cover the entire *Principia*, but mainly the parts that lead to Newton's results on gravity.  What Chandrasekhar does is explain Newton's propositions, translate them into modern notation/language and show you a 'modern' proof, and then, with that knowledge of what is going on, he goes back to Newton's argument and shows the reader how Newton's approach works.  Along the way, he comments on how Newton's ideas harked back to Euclid and, at the same time, anticipated concepts in mechanics that would not be developed until many years later.

It's an amazing, edifying work by one of the greatest astrophysicists of the 20th century.

Comment: Rather than say “with that knowledge of what is going on”, it would be helpful to say “with that idea of what might have gone on”.  See G.E. Smith’s review for some of Chandrasekhar’s erroneous corrections of Newton at http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1996JHA....27..353S

Comment: @MattF.:  Thanks.  I'll have a look at this reference.  It has been a few years since I went through Chandrasekhar's book, but I remember it as a very enlightening experience.

Comment: Chaddrasekhar is not "an edition of Newton". It is only his own digest and only of the first volume.

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend this 1999 version by Cohen & Whitman:

[The Principia: The Authoritative Translation and Guide: Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0520290887)

This edition has comments that help you understand the original. It is also quite cheap.

Comment: This is an excellent edition indeed, the best that I know. With very detailed and professional commentaries on everything.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a free copy offered by its author, (edit: the translator, Ian Bruce),

- http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/newtoncontents.html

Comment: Ah, for a moment I thought the free copy was offered by Newton himself.

Answer (score 4):

[This 2003 edition by Densmore & Donahue](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1888009233) has the following book review

> Makes the great adventure of *Principia* available not only to modern
>   scholars of history of science, but also to nonspecialist
>   undergraduate students of humanities. It moves carefully from Newton's
>   definitions and axioms through the essential propositions, as Newton
>   himself identified them, to the establishment of universal gravitation
>   and elliptical orbits. The guidebook unfolds what is implicit in
>   Newton's words as he himself would have filled in the steps and
>   completes the argument in ways that are authentic and not
>   anachronistic, exactly following Newton's thinking rather than
>   substituting tools of modern calculus or the formulations of modern
>   physics. It is Newton in his own terms. This is a wonderful book.
>   ―Richard S. Westfall